# js: Function to wrap blocks of code

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function to wrap blocks of my code. So I could put something before it and at the end.

```
function wrap(block) {
 console.log("Start")
 block
 console.log("End")
}

// This block needs to be wrapped
let a = body
console.log(content start)
console.log(a)
console.log("content end")
```

---

I want result to be like this.

```
Start
content start
body
content end
End
```

I tried

```
wrap(function() {
let a = body
console.log(content start)
console.log(a)
console.log("content end") 
})
```

But its not working

Comment: I am afraid you have to much more specific. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Can you please create a demo to show what is not working?

Comment: ```function wrap(block) {
 console.log("Start")
 block();
 console.log("End")
}
wrap(function() {
var a = "body"
console.log("content start")
console.log(a);
console.log("content end") 
}) ``` This is working for me all you need to call `block()`function inside `wrap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to call the `block` function passed to `wrap`

```js
function wrap(block) {
  console.log("Start");
  block();
  console.log("End");
}

// This block needs to be wrapped
wrap(function() {
  let a = "body";
  console.log("content start");
  console.log(a);
  console.log("content end");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a function to `wrap` and call it when you need to run the block of code within the function.

```js
function wrap(fn) {
  console.log("Start")
  fn();
  console.log("End")
}

// This block needs to be wrapped
let a = function() {
  console.log("middle");
}

wrap(a);
```